# Poisson parameter interval estimation vs. the CLT: why not simple?

Tags: poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem, confidence-interval, parameter-estimation

I've never been much of a mathematician, and I'm now trying to catch up on some things I should have studied properly many years ago. So forgive me if the question is naive!

I'm relearning statistics, and in particular estimations and hypothesis testing. I have one doubt about the application for the central limit theorem to estimate the mean of a population. Here's my thinking:

1. The CLT applies to any distribution. We can estimate the mean, and the estimator itself follows a normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$. This variance on the estimator is approximated by $s^2/n$ where $s$ is the standard deviation of the samples. And I can use the mean of the samples to approximate the underlying population's mean.
2. If I have a few samples that I believe follows a Poisson distribution, such as the 27 values $2, 4, 1, 4, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 4, 3, 2$, then I can estimate its parameter as the average of these values ($\hat\lambda=
   1.74$) and use the approximation of the estimator's variance to create a 95% confidence interval around that. So my interval would be $\hat\lambda \pm 1.96*s/\sqrt n$, so $1.74 \pm 1.96*0.265$, so a range from $1.22$ to $2.26$.

However I never see such a simple process applied anywhere I look. Instead I see things I haven't looked into yet such as MLE etc. Which definitely look much more complex than this. But why? Is the above incorrect? Why would the CLT fail to deliver, since I'm only looking at estimating a mean? Am I misinterpreting what the mean is, here? Or is it just that it's not very precise and the other methods give a smaller interval?

As you can see from my very unclear explanations, I'm at this stage where I understand a few things but it's quite superficial. If someone takes the time to answer, do not hesitate to do so in a "for dummies" style... I'll be super grateful.

Note: I might be particularly confused by the Poisson distribution because I'm trying to catch up on the topic from the Fundamentals of Biostatistics (Rosner) book, in which the Poisson parameter is $\mu=\lambda t$, rather than the typical $\lambda$ on its own that I see when searching the web (in which case $\mu=\lambda$). This inclusion or not of the time element as a multiplier confuses a little bit the notion of what in this is really the mean and the variance.

Thanks!

P.

Comment: Regarding $\lambda t$ vs. $\lambda$ - the distinction only matters when you have different time intervals in play. Say, you have some data that records number of events in 10-minute intervals, and some more data that records number of events in 1-hour intervals.

Comment: Nitpick - but the CLT only applies to distributions which have finite variance.

Comment: @rubikscube09 this is not nitpicking, this is actually useful. I did want to follow up with the question "when does the CLT not apply, then?" since the textbook I'm referring to did say "any distribution". But being about biostatistics, that book might live in a world where variances are always finite?
Newbie followup question then: are there cases where the data is "not distributed" at all? or is every population distributed in some way even if it follows no particular rules etc.? (thinking of the revenue per session in an A/B test! which is very far from normal or any distribution I know)

Comment: @Pierric - it depends - all data in some sense follows an unknown distribution, or if you are saying, dealing with time series data (stock returns as an obvious example), this distribution can be changing with time/what we call non-stationary.

Comment: On the other hand, the CLT is agnostic about distribution, although most versions of it assume that 1. data is identically distributed, meaning that the distribution each sample is drawn from is the same, 2. data is independent, e.g. what you get on your first draw doesn't influence what you get on the second, and 3. that the variances of each distribution is finite, which is near impossible to check empirically.

Comment: Thanks @rubikscube09 ! I would think those assumptions apply to the context I'm most often interested in (A/B test on online conversions and generated revenue -- which has nothing to do with Poisson, I'm aware, I took a detour while rereading the textbook :) )

Answer (score 1):

Either of the two methods you describe is correct as far as it goes. If you do many statistical analyses of this type, on average you expect at least $95\%$ of them to correctly give you an interval containing the true mean.

(For the CLT, the story is a bit more complicated; it does not apply to *any* distribution. It applies to the Poisson distribution, though, and better than usual, because the Poisson distribution *is* approimately normal when $\lambda$ is large. So we can treat it as a way to simplify some calculations in this case.)

MLE and other Bayesian estimators are more complicated and more *precise* answers to more complicated questions. In particular, the posterior distribution you get from this method can be used to answer any kind of question along the lines of "what is the probability that the rate $\lambda$ satisfies $X$?"

In addition to much more complicated calculations, things are more complicated because you need more input to make it work: a prior distribution for how likely you thought values of $\lambda$ are *before* doing the experiment. (But you can always use an uninformative prior if you have no idea, which is what MLE does.) This, too, is valuable: it makes it easy to combine several experiments, just by taking the output of one as input into the other.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Misha! (I've voted it but I don't have the reputation for it to show). Regarding $\lambda$ being large, I suppose that's not considered to be the case with a value of less than 2, right? Is my range therefore unreliable, in this particular case?

Comment: Sorry, rephrased. In your case, things are fine. When $\lambda$ is large, the normal is a good approximation to a *single* Poisson variable; this doesn't affect the CLT, though we could theoretically use that to get better error bounds in the CLT.

Comment: Thanks @Misha, this makes sense!